# how create vm instance with specific family?

Tags: gcloud

gcloud compute instances create myserver  --enable-nested-virtualization   --zone=europe-north1-a   --machine-type=e2-standard-4 --image-family=centos-stream-8

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:

- The resource 'projects/open-shift-363408/global/images/family/centos-stream-8' was not found

Comment: i' ve resolved with add image project gcloud compute instances create openshift-server --enable-nested-virtualization  --zone=europe-north1-a  --machine-type=e2-standard-4 --image-family=centos-stream-8 --image-project=centos-cloud

Comment: You can answer your own question on Stack overflow I encourage you to do so as it is more likely that it will help others.